# What is the principle behind the code of getting "for loop" output

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm quite confused about the principle of the code getting the result returned from running the for loop, which is **x=c(x,i)**

```
> x<-c()
  for(i in 1:5){
     x=c(x,i)
  }
>  x
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

As what I have understood about for loop, I thought x=i would return the expected result, in this case it would be **1 2 3 4 5**, but the return is 5, only showing result of the last round of loop, I'm wondering why **x=c(x,i)** can collect the result from each round of the loop? what the relationships between x, x in () and i? Like what is the process of value assgining between them?
Hope someone can explain it. Thank you sooo much!!!

```
> x<-c()
  for(i in 1:5){
     x=i
  }
>  x
 [1] 5
```

Comment: Using `<-` for assignment makes things clearer:  `x <- c(x, i)` shows that the value of `c(x, i)` is being put into `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x=c(x,i)` is collecting the data because of the function `c` which concatenates each new value `i` to the previously existing vector `x`.

If you want to get more insights as to what's going on inside the loop, you can use `print(x)`, which will display the value of `x` at each iteration of the loop.

```r
x<-c()
for(i in 1:5){
  x=c(x,i)
  print(x)
}

# [1] 1
# [1] 1 2
# [1] 1 2 3
# [1] 1 2 3 4
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

At each iteration, `x` is being updated with a new value `i`. Without `c`, the previous values of `x` would be deleted from the vector `x`, as shown below.

```r
x<-c()
for(i in 1:5){
  x=i
  print(x)
}
# [1] 1
# [1] 2
# [1] 3
# [1] 4
# [1] 5
```

As @user2554330 pointed out in the comments, it is easier to think about it when using `<-` instead of `=`, as `c(x,i)` is being stored into a new vector `x`. `x` is thus being overwritten at each iteration, which is why you get a different result with `x = i`.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer, I got more understanding from it.

Comment: Hi! I'm glad; if you are satisfied by the answer, you can accept it by clicking on the tick.

Comment: But, it is tricky for me that this is a expression showing a variable (x) stores a vector which contains the variable itself (x),  and another element (i), from my understanding the process is like: for the first interation, i=1, so x<-c(x,1), and then things get tricky for me, as I can't have a reference of how the variable x is assigned the value. Is R gonna ignore the element "x" in the brackets and just assign "i" to the variable "x" because the element "x" has not gained a value yet, and then after assigning  "i=1" to the varaible "x", the element "x" would then gain the value of "i=1"

Comment: But in this case, after element "x" gains the value from the topper environment which is the value of variable "x", then the vector stored in variable "x" should change to x<-(1,1), but for the first interation, the ouput is just 1, to me, one of the element is missing. It is the same for second and ... interation, so I'm still not sure how x<-c(x,1) collects the data and store them from each interation, cos I am stuck in the first interation...

Comment: The variable `x` is being overwritten at each iteration, meaning that the for loop replaces `x` with `c(x, i)` at each iteration. For the first iteration, it replaces `c()` with `c(x,i)` which is `1`. So at the end of iteration 1, `x=1`. Then second iteration, x is being replaced by `c(x,2)`, with `x=1`, so now `x = 1,2`, etc. Without the `c` function, the value of `x` would just be `i`.

Comment: OHHH I get it. Thank you sooo much for the explanation of the "replace" process, so for the first interation, as x has been assigned as c(), which is NULL, so when "i=1", the element "x" in brackets is NULL,  and variable "x<-c() or x<-NULL" is replaced by x<-c(NULL, 1), where x should be missing as it is nothing at this moment, then the variable "x" gets the value of 1, and the process is going on for the next interations.

Comment: Thank you soooo much Maël, your answer is really helpful

Comment: That's it! Well done, you just understood an important feature of R and of programming in general ;)